# Can type hint in python 3 be used to generate docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autodoc

We can indicate the types of function parameters using docstring in python:

```
def f1(a):
    """
    :param a: an input.
    :type a: int
    :return: the input integer.
    :rtype: int
    """
    return a
```

For `f1`, autodoc generates the following document:

```
fun1(a)
    Parameters : a (int) – an input.
    Returns    : the input integer.
    Return type: int
```

In python 3, the types can be indicated by type hint as well:

```
def f2(a: int):
    """
    :param a: an input.
    :return: the input integer.
    :rtype: int
    """
    return a
```

When we run autodoc, it puts the type by the parameter declaration, but not in the description:

```
f2(a: int)
    Parameters : a – an input.
    Returns    : the input integer.
    Return type: int
```

Would it be possible to generate the documentation as `f1` using annotation instead of docstring? I'm using python 3.6. Thank you!

Comment: Obviously you could write code that will do what you want.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1968 Likely with this change you can get support of type annotations out of the box

Comment: Yes, hopefully it will be supported by the Sphinx soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet, from what I'm aware Sphinx yet doesn't support this. The bug referenced in a comment was about the representation of the type-hints and not their positioning.

I do know there's currently an extension for Sphinx that takes care of this for you though, called [sphinx-autodoc-typehints](https://github.com/agronholm/sphinx-autodoc-typehints). You could probably use that for the time being.

Comment: Wonderful, for the time being, I'll use this plugin. Hopefully, this feature will be integrated natively to Sphinx. Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone also wants to use [Napoleon](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51312475/435253) has more details on how to make the two play nice together.