# How to automatically add parameter types in sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, type-hinting, sphinx-napoleon, sphinx-apidoc

I am currently trying to implement automatic documentation creation with Sphinx (using the extensions sphinx-apidoc and napoleon). This works quite well, but it would be even better if the typehints (PEP484 convention) are added automatically to the params list.

I was wondering whether this is possible.

More concretely: (from the [napoleon example](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html#example-google))

```
def function_with_pep484_type_annotations(param1: int, param2: str) -> bool:
    """Example function with PEP 484 type annotations.

    Args:
        param1: The first parameter.
        param2: The second parameter.

    Returns:
        The return value. True for success, False otherwise.

    """
```

This renders as follows:

[image]

The parameters list has all the parameters, but does not attach the types. It is possible to add them manually, but this might introduce future problems when is decided to change the signature.

Example with manual type addition:

```
def function_with_pep484_type_annotations(param1: int, param2: str) -> bool:
    """Example function with PEP 484 type annotations.

    Args:
        param1 (int): The first parameter.
        param2 (str): The second parameter.

    Returns:
        The return value. True for success, False otherwise.

    """
```

which renders as:

[image]

Comment: This is sphinx we're talking about - if the answer isn't "You have to use this monkeypatch", I'll eat a hat.

Comment: This issue seems related: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2738

Comment: The last comment in that issue is exactly what i mean. In the meantime: does some-one know a workaround?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can now use the [sphinx-autodoc-typehints](https://github.com/agronholm/sphinx-autodoc-typehints) extension. It will automatically add the types to the sphinx docstrings when you write in the former example above.

To install, just do:

```
$ pip install sphinx-autodoc-typehints
```

Add `'sphinx_autodoc_typehints'` to the `extensions` list in `conf.py` **after** `'sphinx.ext.napoleon'`, and make sure you also add `napoleon_use_param = True` to `conf.py`.